# Listen again to `$(window).load` after ajax request

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I'm loading an AJAX request of another HTML page, which is then inserted into a DOM element of the current page.

The page I'm getting through AJAX includes `link` references to stylesheets, as well as multiple images, which must be loaded from the server.

I want to execute code ***after all resources from the AJAX call loads***, *including referenced stylesheets and images*.
Note that these stylesheets and images are not directly loaded from AJAX but are loaded as a result of the insertion of the HTML from the AJAX call.

Thus, I'm not looking for the `success:` callback, but rather like another `$(window).load(function () { ... });` after the AJAX call (I've tried listening again to `$(window).load` without success.

Let me know if you need more code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Checking whether a stylesheet has been loaded is difficult to do -- especially cross-browser.   [This article](http://blog.rjzaworski.com/2011/08/firing-events-when-a-stylesheet-finishes-loading/) suggests having an element that will be changed by a known rule in the loaded stylesheet and polling to check whether its style has been changed to detect loading.

Images are easier, and I would expect they take a lot longer to load so you can probably get away with only checking image loading.

```
success: function (html) {
    var imageloads = [];
    $(html).find("img").each(function () {
        var dfd = $.Deferred();
        $(this).on('load', function () {
            dfd.resolve();
        });
        //Image was cached?
        if (this.complete) {
            $(this).trigger('load');
        }
        imageloads.push(dfd);
    });
    $.when.apply(undefined, imageloads).done(function () {
        //images finished loading
    });
}
```

Comment: Great answer! I haven't marked it as accepted yet, because I still have one quick question: In the article you referenced, is there any specific significance in *dynamically* linking to the stylesheet in a `script` tag? In other words, would simply including the `<link>` be sufficient?

Comment: @AlbertXing including the `<link>` how?  If you append it to the HTML it would have the same effect.

Comment: The article states to dynamically add the link element through JS, and I was just wondering if simply having the link element already in the head element of the HTML file would still work with the tactic.

Comment: @AlbertXing you mean when the page initially loads or are you talking about appending the `<link>` element?

Comment: I'm wondering if the script still works if the stylesheet is **not** loaded dynamically from the JS (you know, like when you just have the `<link>` element in the `<head>` of the HTML file. In other words, not appending the `<link>` element but rather just having it in the HTML.

Comment: @AlbertXing I would think it would -- I could be wrong but I thought that CSS files were downloaded serially.

Comment: Sure, just wondering about it if you knew. Thanks,! (P.S. Somehow I can't mention you)